# Searching Eagle library issue

Tags: eaglecad, library

I am new to Eagle (using 6.5.0) and I have huge problems with search in library functionality. If, for example, I want to search for LM358, and I type just 358 in the search field, it doesn't find anything. I have to search "LM358" specifically in order to find it. Goes the same for any component.

Am I missing something ? Is there an option that I've messed up or that I have to change in order to use part of the component name in order to find it ?

**Searching "358":**

[image]

**Searching "LM358":**

[image]

Comment: Try a wildcard like "*358"

Comment: Well... No search is working like this, I don't know why all the downvotes ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  Andy Aka mentioned in a comment you can use wildcards when searching for parts. Many parts have a suffix to indicate the package so for that part you could search on `*358*`:

[image: Eagle find part]

However if you already know the prefix you can search on `LM358*` to find all the package variants.